How to execute each scenario outlines in parallel, but the outline examples of each scenario in sequential manner
Considering I have the parallel tag set to true at the feature file level, Can I have the scenario outline examples executed in sequential manner?

Test.feature:

@parallel=true
@MS_Feature1_Test

@TestCase1
Scenario Outline: This is to validate TC1
Given ...
Then ....
Examples:
  |Steps        |Outcome|
  |'Call API 1' |'PASS' |  
  |'Call API 2' |'PASS' |
  |'Call API 3' |'PASS' |

@TestCase2
Scenario Outline: This is to validate TC2
Given ...
Then ....
Examples:
  |Steps        |Outcome|
  |'Call API 1' |'PASS' |  
  |'Call API 2' |'PASS' |
  |'Call API 3' |'PASS' |

As per the above feature file, I would want @TestCase1 and @TestCase2 to start execution in parallel, but the Steps(Examples) "Call API 1" , "Call API 2" and "Call API3" to be executed in sequential manner.
Is there a way I can achieve this in Karate?

Why don't you just move the outlines into separate feature files. Then @parallel=false on each should get you what you want.

Will the feature files get executed in parallel then? But the number of scenario outlines are too many so maintaining them would become an overhead so thinking of a solution that can have them in the same file

@ChethanSwaroop I don't have any other solutions in mind, but you are welcome to contribute code to karate to improve it
